# Cup products in compactly supported and twisted cohomology of manifold.

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology, poincare-duality

I know very well about the cup product in ordinary cohomology. My question is that how we compute the different cup product with twisted or compactly supported cohomology i.e, 
$$\cup:H^{*}(M,\mathbb{Q}^{w})\times H^{*}(M,\mathbb{Q}^{w})\longrightarrow H^{*}(M,\mathbb{Q})$$
$$\cup:H^{*}(M,\mathbb{Q}^{w})\times H^{*}(M,\mathbb{Q}^{w})\longrightarrow H_{c}^{*}(M,\mathbb{Q})$$
$$\cup:H_{c}^{*}(M,\mathbb{Q}^{w})\times H_{c}^{*}(M,\mathbb{Q}^{w})\longrightarrow H_{c}^{*}(M,\mathbb{Q})$$
$$\cup:H_{c}^{*}(M,\mathbb{Q})\times H_{c}^{*}(M,\mathbb{Q})\longrightarrow H_{c}^{*}(M,\mathbb{Q})$$
where  $H^{*}(M,\mathbb{Q}),\,H_{c}^{*}(M,\mathbb{Q})$ and $H^{*}(M,\mathbb{Q}^{w})$ are ordinary, compactly supported and twisted cohomology ring     of manifold respectively.